# How to choose a specific row in a file as the headers for Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a fixed width data file which looks like this:

```
  PRINT STREAM NO.  1
   TIME             X         Y          Z        
   0.0000      1.4700E+14  9.3100E+15  0.0000                     
   2.0000E+00  4.5102E+13  9.2565E+15  5.2419E+10 
      .            .           .           . 
      .            .           .           . 
      .            .           .           . 
      .            .           .           .
```

I would like to plot the data in Gnuplot with Time on the x-axis and X,Y,Z on the y-axis (they all have the same units) and use X,Y and Z as plot titles in the key/legend. If the line "PRINT STREAM NO.  1" wasn't there I could use `set key autotitle columnhead` to do this, but I don't know how I would go about doing this with XYZ in the second row?

**EDIT**

Sorry didn't mention this earlier but the number of rows and columns is variable from file to file, the above is just an example of the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Check `help skip`.

**Code:**

```
### skip some initial lines
reset session

$Data <<EOD
  PRINT STREAM NO.  1
   TIME             X         Y          Z        
   0.0000      1.4700E+14  9.3100E+15  0.0000                     
   2.0000E+00  4.5102E+13  9.2565E+15  5.2419E+10 
EOD

set key autotitle columnhead

plot $Data u 1:2 skip 1 w lp, \
     ''    u 1:3 skip 1 w lp, \
     ''    u 1:4 skip 1 w lp
     
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:** (with variable number of columns, result same as above)

```
### skip some initial lines
reset session

$Data <<EOD
  PRINT STREAM NO.  1
   TIME             X         Y          Z
   0.0000      1.4700E+14  9.3100E+15  0.0000
   2.0000E+00  4.5102E+13  9.2565E+15  5.2419E+10
EOD

set key autotitle columnhead

plot for [col=2:*] $Data u 1:(column(col)) skip 1 w lp
### end of code
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention it in the original question but the files can contain up to 10 columns and 2000 rows each so setting the `plot` and `skip` commands per column would be quite time consuming. Is there a shorter way to do it by any chance?

Comment: OK, now I understand that the number of columns and rows is variable from file to file.How many header lines to skip do you have? Always one or is is variable as well?

Comment: Thankfully the number of lines to skip is always the same. First there is an empty line, followed by the line `PRINT STREAM NO.  1` followed by the line with the column headers. I would like to skip the empty line and `PRINT STREAM NO. 1` and use the column headers in the third line in the key.

Comment: then just use `skip 2`. As a friendly reminder: please always describe what exactly you have and what exactly you want and what you have coded so far.

Comment: Thank you I will keep that in mind. If you don't mind could you please explain what the `[col=2:*]` portion of the plot command means and the significance of `plot for` as opposed to just `plot`?

Comment: `plot for [col=2:*]` is a loop and equivalent to plotting all columns from 2 to as many there are. Type `help plot for` in the gnuplot console.